# Java: Spring : How to pass params to the constructor dynamically?

Tags: java, spring

Pretend that I have a class:

```
public class Person {

 private final String first;
 private final String last;
 private final Address address;

 public Person(String first, String last, Address address){
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.address = address;
 }

 public String getFirst() {
  return first;
 }

 public String getLast() {
  return last;
 }

 public Address getAddress() {
  return address;
 }
}
```

**And I have a proxy class for the above as :**

```
public class PersonProxy
{
    private Person person;

    // --Other properties---

    public PersonProxy( Person person)
    {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

**We used to create an instance of the PersonProxy this way:**

```
PersonProxy proxy = new PersonProxy(new Person("Betty", "Kale" , "some address"));
```

But we are moving to Spring recently and would like to declare these 2 classes as beans in the context file but want to pass those params, in the constructor of the Person class, dynamically when creating an object of the proxy.
How can declare that kind of bean for those 2 classes in the context file and how can I create the instance of the PersonProxy class using those beans to replace:

```
PersonProxy proxy = new PersonProxy(new Person("Betty", "Kale" , "some address"));
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the point of meking such a class a Spring bean. But the easiest way is to use JavaConfig and add an `@Bean`-annotated method in your configuration class, that creates the object, in Java.

Comment: yeah, it's not clear why you just can't have those instances created without spring, just like you did before. you don't have to migrate all of your object management to spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Person as :
Person person  = context.getBean(  Person.class,"Betty", "Kale" , "some address");

And then create the PersonProxy as :
PersonProxy proxy=  context.getBean(PersonProxy.class, person  );

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do that is using a `FactoryBean`, e.g. creating a `PersonProxyFactoryBean`. See [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean) for more details on FactoryBeans.